# how to move bottom linespace in fontforge

Tags: fonts, resize, spacing, margins, fontforge

This is the first time I use fontforge, and I have never used similar programs. Starting from a font, I imported it into fontforge and decreased its scale (transform -> uniformscale) but now, the margins around the font are too wide.

After manually adjusting the width margins, I was able to move the top margin by decreasing the value of fontInfo > general >ascendent, but I can't move the bottom margin to match the bottom of the letter. How can I do it?[image description is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ae1pP.png).